# How to Retrieve Feature Weights and Formula from SVC Classification

Tags: machine-learning, learning

I am quite new to skit-learn. I have been working on a SVC Classification problem which seems to be yielded good results. I am using an SVC Polynomial Classifier @ 40 degrees; please see attached (oops can't attach).

How can I retrieve the Feature Weights and General formula